# Does the treatment of string literals depend on the left hand side of an assignment?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, string-literals

Trying to wrap my head around Chapters 5.7 to 5.9 in "The C Programming Language", handling with multi-dimensional arrays, arrays of pointers etc., I came up with the following observation:

If in the code below `foo` is declared as a pointer to a char array, and I later want to assign a pointer of type `char` to it, I must precede the string literal with a  `&` symbol. However, if I declare `bar` as a pointer, the very same operation is possible without a `&` symbol.

```
char (*foo)[3]; // creates a single pointer to a char array of size 3
char *bar;      // creates a single pointer to char

int main()
{
    foo = &"AB";
    bar = "AB";
    
    return 0;
}
```

The disassembly (64bit Macho-O) seems (at least to the beginner's eye) to perform the same operations for both assignments:

```
Disassembly of section __TEXT,__text:

0000000100003f80 _main:
100003f80: 55                           push    rbp
100003f81: 48 89 e5                     mov rbp, rsp
100003f84: 31 c0                        xor eax, eax
100003f86: 48 8d 0d 7b 00 00 00         lea rcx, [rip + 123]        // address of 'bar'
100003f8d: 48 8d 15 6c 00 00 00         lea rdx, [rip + 108]        // address of 'foo'
100003f94: c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00         mov dword ptr [rbp - 4], 0
100003f9b: 48 8d 35 08 00 00 00         lea rsi, [rip + 8]          // address pointing to 'AB'-String
100003fa2: 48 89 32                     mov qword ptr [rdx], rsi    // store address of 'AB' in 'foo'
100003fa5: 48 89 31                     mov qword ptr [rcx], rsi    // store address of 'AB' in 'bar'
100003fa8: 5d                           pop rbp
100003fa9: c3                           ret

Disassembly of section __TEXT,__cstring:

0000000100003faa __cstring:
100003faa: 41 42                        <unknown>
100003fac: 00                           <unknown>


Disassembly of section __DATA,__common:

0000000100004000 _foo:
...

0000000100004008 _bar:
...
```

Since the book I am reading is my first contact to C, I'm afraid that I'm missing something obvious here. Wouldn't it be more logical, if I would need the `&`-symbol in both cases?

Comment: " string pointer" sounds like using _string_ as if it was a type - which it is not.  " I later want to assign a string pointer to it," is better as " I later want to  assign a `char` pointer to it,".

Answer (score 3):

A string literal in C has type "array of char" with a size equal to the number of characters including the terminating null byte.  This means `"AB"` has type `char [3]`.

In *most* cases, when an array is used in an expression it decays to a pointer to the first element.  This is what happens in the case of `bar = "AB"`.  The string constant on the right side decays to type `char *` which can be assigned directly to `bar`.

One of the cases where this decay does *not* happen is when the array is the subject of the `&` operator.  So taking the address of an array of type `char [3]` yields a pointer of type `char (*)[3]` which matches the type of `foo`.

Comment: @attachedy In the expression `**foo+1`, the pointer `foo` is first dereferenced yielding an array of type `char [3]`.  That array is then converted to a pointer of type `char *` which is again dereferenced, yielding the the first character in the array, namely `'A'`.  The value 1 is then added to that character yielding the character `'B'`.  If you were to change the string constant to `"AX"` for example you would still get `'B'` as a result.

Comment: @attachedy In that case, it's the same as `(*foo)[1]` which first dereferences the pointer to yield an array, then retrieves the element at index 1 from the array.

Answer (score 2):

OK, lets assume that every instance of `"AB"` is stored at memory location `0xDEADBEEF`. The expression `"AB"` is an array expression, and in most context will return the address of its first element. Two notable exceptions are the `&` and `sizeof` operators. In `&"AB"` and `sizeof "AB"` the array would bee seen as an array, and not the address of its first element.

`char (*foo)[3] = &"AB";` will (on most architectures) initialize `foo` to have the value `0xDEADBEEF` which is the address of `"AB"`. In the expression `&"AB"`, the array `"AB"` is treated as an array, and `&` returns its address.

`char *bar = "AB";` will initialize `bar` to point at `A`, and guess what, on most architectures that would be the same address as `"AB"`, which is `0xDEADBEEF`. Here the array `"AB"` was converted to a pointer to its first element.

So both `foo` and `bar` points at the same memory location, but at different objects. `foo` points at a sequence of 3 bytes, but `bar` points at a single byte.

Since `foo` points at an array, the expression `*foo` is the array `foo` points at. In most context, array expressions yields a pointer to the first element in the array, so in the expression `**foo`, the subexpression `*foo` is the array `"AB"` (of type `char[3]`), but is converted to a pointer to `A` (of type `char *`). The second * in front of `*foo` dereferences the pointer to `A`, and returns `A`

To summarize:

- `foo` is a pointer to `char [3];` with the value `0xDEAFBEEF`
- `*foo` is the array `foo` points at, which is `"AB"` and has type `char [3]`
- In most contexts, `*foo` gets converted to `char *`, still with the value `0xDEADBEEF`
- As exceptions to previous point, in the expressions `&*foo` and `sizeof *foo`, `*foo` is not converted, but remains `"AB"`.
- Dereferencing `*foo` like this `**foo`, will return `A` (`foo==0xDEADBEEF`, `*foo=="AB"->0xDEADBEEF==bar`, `**foo==*0xDEADBEEF==*bar=='A'`)